# Get model position inside a shader

Tags: three.js, shader

My current code to add a skybox to my game looks like this:

```
var sky = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 15), 
    new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: gradientShader.vertex,
        fragmentShader: gradientShader.fragment,
        side: THREE.BackSide
    })
);
```

To get the position of the model with which to do calculations on, I currently just provide it as a uniform. `ypos: { type: "f", value: 0 }`

Unfortunately, that also means I have to update it whenever the model moves.

Is there a way to get the model's position from within the shader itself? That way I would never have to set a uniform for it, and it would automatically use the new position when the model moved.

Comment: only through uniforms.